# удалить некоторые элементы массива

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Например, у меня есть массив [5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2]. Требуется удалить некоторые элементы до того, что массив должен отсортироваться. Требуется сделать это за минимальное количество ходов

**Входные данные**

В первой строке записано целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000) — количество чисел

Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел p[i] (1 ≤ p[i] ≤ n, p[i] ≠ p[j] при i ≠ j) — последовательность чисел.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите целое число — минимальное количество действий, необходимое для сортировки массива

Comment: Ну во первых, хорошо бы было нам показать Input и Otput(то есть протокол), дальше уже решать, а так если нужно вычеркивать элементы массива, пока он не встанет по возрастанию, то находим минимальный элемент массива, а от него считаем(все до него удаляем, думаю понятно почему так), м повторяем процесс, до того момента пока не дойдем до ответа

Comment: @ПростоКодер не всегда) иногда надо удалить минимальный именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переформулируем задачу. Нужно найти максимальную возрастающую последовательность. Почему это так - думаю понятно. Именно она останется неудалённой.

Методов для решения есть глобально 2. Это бинарный поиск с динамикой. Или дерево.
Напишу сначала тривиальное решение за квадрат.

```
// fill F - array 1
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
    for (int j=0; j<i; ++j)
        if (a[j] <= a[i])
            F[i] = max (F[i], F[j] + 1);
```

Теперь есть 2 варианта ускорения. Или используем структуру чтобы убрать 2 цикл и заменить на поиск максимума в дереве отрезков. Или используем бинарный поиск (последнее не очевидно).

В общем вот ссылка дальше сами. http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log

P.S. я предполагаю что отсортировать надо по возрастанию. Если нет - сделайте тоже самое только в обратную сторону и найдите лучший результат.